# Delay graying out of page with BlockUI

Tags: jquery, blockui

I'm using BlockUI and jQuery to block access to a page when some action can take some time to be performed on the server (it executes several database queries but that is not important). The actions are mostly performed quickly and every now and then it takes a few seconds. To avoid unness. blinking:

Is it possible to:
- Start the ajax request to perform the action
- block the UI invisibly
- if after 500 ms (a setting) the answer is not there, re-block the UI and now with graying out etc.
- when finished / on error, unblock the UI.

How should I do something like that or should I do it differently or is there another plugin that can perform this out of the box?

Currently I use the following code to generate the effect:

```
DoRequest = function( param, name ) {
    $.blockUI( { message: null, fadeIn: 0, fadeOut: 0, overlayCSS: { opacity: 0.0 } } );
    blockUIPhase1 = setTimeout( function(){ 
        $.unblockUI( { fadeOut: 0 } );
        $.blockUI( { message: "Even geduld a.u.b.", overlayCSS: { opacity: 0.0 } } );
    }, 1000 );
    $.ajax( {
        url:        "screen.json",
        dataType:   'json',
        success: function( data ) {
            // ....
        },  
        complete: function() {
            if ( blockUIPhase1 != undefined ) clearTimeout( blockUIPhase1 );
            $.unblockUI( { fadeOut: 0 } );
        }
    } );
```

Comment: With the use of `setTimeout` this should be fairly straightforward to achieve. Can you please post the code you are currently using.

Comment: @Rory: I'm starting to implement this, If I have some wrorking code I will update the question. Currently I use BlockUI in the classic way so it will always go dark and light again. NB: the setTimeout is for unblocking the UI automatically. I do not want to unblock the UI automatically but block the UI without a visible clue and only after a timeout use a visible clue (darken) to show that the quey takes a lot of time.